# How do I get script in project.json to execute only when debugging

Tags: node.js, npm

So I have my prepublish script which runs webpack in prod

```
"scripts": {
  "prepublish": [
    "npm install",
    "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --env.prod"
 ],
  "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
```

But how do I run a script here which only executes in debug ?

What I want to achieve is to make webpack run without --env.prod each time the project builds in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a shell script that checks `NODE_ENV` and runs webpack with or without `--env.prod` depending on the result:

```
"scripts": {
  "prepublish": "./scripts/prepublish"
}
```

scripts/prepublish:

```
#!/bin/bash

npm install
if [[ $NODE_ENV = "production" ]]; then
    node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --env.prod
else
    node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

An elegant solution would be to set an environment variable on production, for example: `WEBPACK_FLAGS=--env.prod`. Then you can do:

```
"scripts": {
  "prepublish": "webpack $WEBPACK_FLAGS"
}
```

Or you can simply pass the value directly:

```
"scripts": {
  "prepublish": "webpack --env.$NODE_ENV"
}
```

You can also do an if statement like SimpleJ suggested:

```
"scripts": {
  "prepublish": "if [[ $NODE_ENV = "prod" ]]; then webpack --env.prod"; else webpack; fi"
}
```

I might be mistaken, but I believe that webpack will always be aliased to `webpack` so that you can replace `node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js` with `webpack`.